# separating citations with 'though see' in biblatex within parencite

Tags: biblatex, citing, text

I want to use biblatex to write in-text: (Piaget, 1954; though see Baillargeon 1985, 1987), but I'm not sure how to include words between references. I tried:

`\parencite[though see]{piaget1955child, baillargeon1985object, baillargeon1987object}`

but this includes 'though see' at the end of all citations, rather than in the middle. I also tried a convoluted combination of `\parentext` and `\cite` etc but was wondering if there is a faster solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the multi-cite command `\parencites`

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\parencites{sigfridsson}[though see][]{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}

\parencites{sigfridsson}[though see][]{knuth:ct:a}{knuth:ct:b}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998; though see Knuth 1984, 1986)//(Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998; though see Knuth 1984, 1986)]